# Setting vanity profile names?

Tags: support, display-names

Is there a way, that I am not finding, to have a vanity profile name?

On LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter, etc I am KellCOMnet; on stackoverflow I am /users/464228/christopher-kelly.

If this is not currently available, what is the community’s thoughts on this feature?

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm pretty sure this question is asking for a vanity *URL*.

Comment: As [close as you can get](https://stackexchange.com/users/4485506/rob) is that link, which is shown on my Profile next to the - you can get there by clicking my name ➨

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to edit your username. If you want to, go to your profile and click on the "Edit profile and settings" tab on the top of the page. Here is [a direct link to the editing page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).

On your profile, go up to the top:

[image: "Activity" tab open with arrow pointing at the tabs]

Go to the "Edit profile and settings tab":

[image: Circled "Edit profile and settings" tab]

Edit your display name in the box:

[image: Circled "Display name" editing box]

Save at the bottom of the page:

[image: Buttons on profile: "Save changes just for this community", "Save and copy changes to all public communities", or "cancel"]

Now you have a better name:

[image: A user profile with the name "Different, Cooler Name"]

Answer (score 6):

You can set your username to whatever you want. I do! The issue with /user/username is *usernames are not unique* on SE and it would need a massive re-design of how we think of profiles.

Your profile is *actually* linked to your userid (and in DB terms that's pretty much your primary key), and your user name is something changeable (every 30 days cause some people abuse this and we can't have nice things because of this) at any point.

SO you *already* have a vanity profile name (and I set my "real name" to Firstname "Journeyman Geek" Sirname - cause no one would recognise my real name), and a real name field you can set/change to anything.

Displaying your username as /user/vanityname is implausible since there's no constraint on that being unique and that's going to break a ton of accounts if changed.

Comment: Wha, What do you mean? I don't think it will [change much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=month&search=tim).

Answer (score 1):

The "display name" field you're referring to *is* a "vanity profile name". For example, see my username; the way I set it is by simply setting the usual "display name".

There is *also* a "real name" field at the *bottom* of your profile settings; it's used in a completely different manner (for Stack Overflow Jobs and Teams). It is not shown publicly anywhere (except within your Developer Story and within any Teams you're a member of).